# How do I flush the cache in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the command line to create an environment using the following command:

```
eb create staging -i t2.small
```

I then get the following error message:

```
2018-07-31 20:13:16    ERROR   Each option setting in configuration file .ebextensions/options.config in application version app-c8f2-180731_201302 must be a map. Update each option setting in the configuration file.
```

When I delete the options.config and run the command again, I get exactly the same error. More fully:

```
2018-07-31 20:17:04    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2018-07-31 20:17:05    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-413395812799 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2018-07-31 20:17:06    ERROR   Each option setting in configuration file .ebextensions/options.config in application version app-c8f2-180731_201651 must be a map. Update each option setting in the configuration file.
2018-07-31 20:17:07    ERROR   Failed to launch environment.

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to launch environment.
```

It therefore seems that Elastic Beanstalk is caching an old version of the program.

If so, how do I flush the cache?

If not, why do I still get the error even after I delete the file?

Comment: got any solution  for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting the file and running create again on an environment that has already been initialized.

Try running [`eb deploy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) to push new changes to your already initialized Elastic Beanstalk environment instead.